# is it possible to know a file(say .txt) is open in client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I need to know is it possible to know a file(say .txt) is open or used in any applications  before uploading it using ajax in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this from JavaScript. There is a [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) which allows you to access local files under certain circumstances but you can't examine open file handles of other processes.